# re How to change HP boot logo on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, hp, logo

Each time I power on my HP Probook 440 G2, it will show a customize photo before booting into Ubuntu - at that time, it would be prompted in the bottom left corner of the screen:
"Press ESC for Setup Menu"

I found that it could be changed on Windows, and changing it related to BIOS multiplication - https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01646879.

And it was said somewhere, on Linux, it involves "EFI" folder, but my "EFI" folder was empty.

Is anyone here know how to do this?

These were the output of "sudo blkid":
/dev/sdb5: UUID="4076ff65-4166-480b-9d65-27642c523b78" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="96f2f010-05"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Products" UUID="9e148580-9ad0-4070-9364-3e37f3254c4e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9e62b9bd-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Projects" UUID="27124deb-e165-4b7f-847e-0a2dfbd268ea" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9e62b9bd-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Goods" UUID="13f2ed7d-fc42-4e41-ac28-be6605fb21f5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9e62b9bd-03"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Archives" UUID="3dbd2523-74c0-49de-8bd6-e248d089cbea" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9e62b9bd-04"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="6671-F0DE" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="96f2f010-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="F976-5B53" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="96f2f010-02"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"

Comment: This happens before Ubuntu starts so you cannot change it via Ubuntu settings.

Comment: @MilanQi has the computer came with Windows OS? If yes.. that OS might have the software intended for this. `Access the Computer Setup utility, and select System Configuration.`

Comment: can you provide the output of `sudo blkid` command once you are in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: It came with Windows OS, and I uninstalled Windows and changed to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: These was the output of "sudo blkid":

Comment: @MianQi from the output you provided.. there seems no partition which is mentioned in the link you provided. Probably while installing Ubuntu you might have chosen to erase disk n install Ubuntu.

Comment: `The HP EFI partition is viewable on the hard drive and is labeled as HP_TOOLS.` from the link you provided. I am talking about this partition might have erased while you were installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I found folder "EFI" was empty, can I restore it or I should reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Or it could be done by update BIOS?